# How can I get permutations of items from two subqueries in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, permutation

Lets say I have two subqueries:

```
SELECT Id AS Id0 FROM Table0

=>

Id0
---
1
2
3

and

SELECT Id AS Id1 FROM Table1

=>


Id1
---
4
5
6
```

How do I combine these to get the query result:

```
Id0 Id1
-------
1   4
1   5
1   6
2   4
2   5
2   6
3   4
3   5
3   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT A.Id0, B.Id1
FROM (SELECT Id AS Id0 FROM Table0) A, 
     (SELECT Id AS Id1 FROM Table1) B
```

Grégoire

Answer (score 1):

Cartesian join, a join with no join condition

```
select id0.id as id0, id1.id as id1 
from id0, id1
```

alternatively you can use the CROSS JOIN syntax if you prefer

```
select id0.id as id0, id1.id as id1 
from id0 cross join id1
```

you can order your query if you want a specific order, from your example it looks like you want

```
select id0.id as id0, id1.id as id1
from id0 cross join id1 order by id0.id, id1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT
    Table0.Id0,
    Table1.Id1
FROM
    Table0
Full Join Table1 on
    1=1